# Can I do a Selective Color effect in Photoshop Elements?

Tags: post-processing, effect, photoshop-elements, selective-color

In TipSquirrel there is a tutorial on "Unifying an image with Selective Color"
By Michael Hoffman.  Can this be done with Photoshop Elements.

I am not very knowledgable on Photoshop Elements as I generally use Lightroom 4.

Comment: google: photoshop elements selective colour tutorial, and you'll find plenty of matches.

Comment: The Hoffman tutorial refers to a Photoshop adjustment layer that lets you apply a colour cast to an image. Not the usual selective color technique (mostly B&W image with some small thing in color). So those google results aren't very helpfule.  Sue, if you're still looking, you'll probably get better help in [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) or 
[Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can use either '[sponging](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDwQtwIwAQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nK3572EBuAI&ei=iXkIUbWRF7GwiQeinICQAw&usg=AFQjCNECZ_vOXm4jxsKzPyGp9p3aNk0lNw&bvm=bv.41642243,d.aGc)' or '[masking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw1RQJUdiAo)'
Which will both achieve the effect i believe you are trying to achieve.
Masking is much simpler and more effective i believe but its up to you.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Those two, and my answer which I've deleted, deal with something different than the "selective coloring" referred to in the Michael Hoffman video.  That is a tool in Photoshop that lets you apply a color cast to the entire image.  Not the selective coloring where you have a black and white image with a selected area remaining in color.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the layer, and on the top layer convert it to black and white.  Then add a layer mask and mask through to the underlying colour layer the area you want to be in colour.

Then flatten and save.  Simples :)

EDIT: **YES** you can do this in Elements - in "Expert mode"... [I've done it myself!](http://www.flickr.com/photos/miketendler/8503428319/)